# How to prepare chart with different interval on different rangeselectionbutton?

Tags: highcharts

I'm using HIghcharts/Highstock with area type.
I have data for last 10 years. each day with 1 entry.
For last week I have 4 entry for each day. (28 data)
For last one day I have 1 entry for each 10 mins. (240 data)

I have array including all above data.

While I am prepare chart, for 1W and 1M, due to above data its not working properly. So when 1W clicked, I want to render only 28 entry and 1M click it should render only 30 entry (not 28 entry for last week) but here problem comes and i can't skip those records.

any help appreciated.

Thanks
J

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. Please read this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question.

Comment: Hi @J.Shah, Could you provide us with some live example that presents a problem?

Comment: Hello Sorry for late response. I have managed with dynamic data set with range in chart.